# Placeholder and on select in combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, jqxcombobox

I have the following code which outputs me a combobox:

```
<html>
<head>
// Included JS library
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () 
{                
    var moduleAutoSuggest = getModuleAutoSuggestOption();

    // Create a jqxComboBox
    $("#jqxWidget").jqxComboBox(
    { 
        source: moduleAutoSuggest,
         placeHolder            : "text ...",
        width: '250', 
        height: '25px',
        disabled : false,
        searchMode: 'containsignorecase',
        autoComplete: true
    });

    obj = '';
      $('#jqxWidget').on('select', function (event) 
      {
                var args = event.args;
                if (args != undefined) {
                    var item = event.args.item;
                    if (item != null) 
                    {
                        obj = item;
                        printSelectedValue(obj);
                    }
                }
    });
});

function getModuleAutoSuggestOption()
{
    var moduleAutoSuggestOption = 
        [
            {"id" : "ALL_ICONS", "label":"All Icons"},
            {"id" : "ALL_LOGOS", "label":"All Logos"},
            {"id" : "ARTICLE", "label":"Newest Article"},
            {"id" : "ARTICLE_SUMMARY", "label":"Headlines For 10 Newest Articles"}
    ];

    return moduleAutoSuggestOption;
}   
</script>

<div id='content'></div>
        <div id='jqxWidget'>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It gives me a working combobox, the issue is, the **placeHolder** attribute is not working and If I click on the input text, the selected value doesnt get clearer

Any help will be appreaciated

Comment: Link to a fiddle or demo? Also, just looking at your code, you might want to format the semicolon for placeHolder, it is throwing a red flag for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, I created a working example that seems to be functioning identically to the jqwidgets example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/n9EWq/). Was there something about this functionality you were looking to change?

```js
$(function () 
{                
    var moduleAutoSuggest = getModuleAutoSuggestOption();

    // Create a jqxComboBox
    $("#jqxWidget").jqxComboBox({ 
        source: moduleAutoSuggest,
        placeHolder: "text ...",
        width: '250', 
        height: '25px',
        disabled: false,
        searchMode: 'containsignorecase',
        autoComplete: true
    });

    obj = '';
    $('#jqxWidget').on('select', function (event){
      var args = event.args;
      if (args != undefined) {
        var item = event.args.item;
        if (item != null) 
        {
          obj = item;
          printSelectedValue(obj);
        }
      }
    });
});

function getModuleAutoSuggestOption()
{
    return [
            {"id" : "ALL_ICONS", "label":"All Icons"},
            {"id" : "ALL_LOGOS", "label":"All Logos"},
            {"id" : "ARTICLE", "label":"Newest Article"},
            {"id" : "ARTICLE_SUMMARY", "label":"Headlines For 10 Newest Articles"}
    ];

}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxcombobox.js"></script>

<div id='content'></div>
<div id='jqxWidget'>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, my includes were different than yours, that was the difference.
Thanks a lot :)